# error in demo script with createReadStream

Tags: node.js

Why do I get this error in node.js? The idea is to write something just after the bunch is completely read in order to avoid that putting data in earlier than reading the content of the file. Because they ask for more details I put some dummy text here in order to fullfill the requirement of minimal text.

```
> pi@raspberrypi:~/nodetest $ sudo node readstream.js
VAR1=2
VAR3=4
Fri Jan 06 2017 12:11:37 GMT+0000 (UTC)
Fri Jan 06 2017 12:33:14 GMT+0000 (UTC)
Fri Jan 06 2017 12:34:12 GMT+0000 (UTC)
appending
appending
appending
appending
appending
appending
appending

Fri Jan 06 2017 12:11:37 GMT+0000 (UTC)
Fri Jan 06 2017 12:33:14 GMT+0000 (UTC)
Fri Jan
Fri Jan 06 2017 12:11:37 GMT+0000 (UTC)
Fri Jan 06 2017 12:33:14 GMT+0000 (UTC)
Fri Jan
end

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: EBADF, write
```

My code:

```
fs = require('fs');
path = 'config.txt';
readableStream = fs.createReadStream(path);
readableStream.setEncoding('utf8');
readableStream.once('data', function(data){ console.log(data); }  );

readableStream.once('end', function(){
 fs.open(path, 'a+', function(err, fd){

  readStream = fs.createReadStream(null, {fd: fd, encoding: 'utf8', start: 14, end: 100});
  readStream.once('data', function(data){ console.log(data);} );
  readStream.once('data', console.log); // shorter
  readStream.once('end', function(){
     console.log('end');
     try {
      readStream.removeListener('data', function(data){} );
      writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(null, {fd: fd, encoding: 'utf8', flags: 'a+'});
      writeStream.write('appending\n'); // not working???
     }
     catch(err) {
      console.log('error: [' + err.message + ']');
     };

  } );

 } );
} );
```

Comment: It seems strange, looks like it is trying to open the same file on the stream end event. I think that is the problem. But can you provide more information? Does it say which line is causing the error? Do you have a call stack?

Comment: <code>
pi@raspberrypi:~/nodetest $ sudo node readstream.js
VAR1=2
VAR3=4
Fri Jan 06 2017 12:11:37 GMT+0000 (UTC)
Fri Jan 06 2017 12:33:14 GMT+0000 (UTC)
Fri Jan 06 2017 12:34:12 GMT+0000 (UTC)
appending
appending
appending
appending
appending
appending
appending

Fri Jan 06 2017 12:11:37 GMT+0000 (UTC)
Fri Jan 06 2017 12:33:14 GMT+0000 (UTC)
Fri Jan
Fri Jan 06 2017 12:11:37 GMT+0000 (UTC)
Fri Jan 06 2017 12:33:14 GMT+0000 (UTC)
Fri Jan
end

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: EBADF, write</code>

Comment: Try editing your question to include more information, it doesn't fit well in the comments

Comment: You could try to add `readStream.once('error', function (err) {` then log it. Maybe with that we can see what the real error is.

Comment: If i add readStream.once('error', function(err){console.log('error: ['+ err + ']');} ); there is no difference in the output